# How to use PHP Ajax.Request onSubmit

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am trying to use a form to send an prototype ajax request to a php script via post and then display an alert window for success and failure

I am currently using this code

```
<div id="reservationRequestForm">
   <form name="requestReservationForm" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('admin/process/process_reservation_request.php', {onSuccess: function() {alert('Success');} , onFailure: function() {alert('Failure');}, method:'post'}; return false;">

....

   <input type="submit" class="buttonGreen" value="Send Request" onClick="hideDiv('reservationRequestForm');"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

I do not want the response to be processed either (it is empty anyways). I only want to know if it succeeded or failed.

In addition. I would like the form to degrade gracefully when js is disabled.

Right now this code does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using prototype instead of jQuery :)

Comment: could you post more of the html? And what is currently happening? is the form submitting at all (it shouldn't)?

Comment: haha ok then how is it done in jQuery? What makes it so much better?

Comment: it seems the form is not submitting at all. The php script sends out an email and I do no receive anything so I do not think it is running.

Comment: @rube, see my answer below. Also, jquery and prototype are both more than capable of handling this. if you have existing prototype code and you're more familiar with it, then there's no need to change. That said, it doesn't hurt to have a look around and see what meets your needs best. jquery, prototype, mootools, extjs, and others all have their areas of focus -- strengths and weaknesses. I would hesitate to say one is *better* than the others, but I will say jquery has a larger following than the others.

Comment: ok I will check out jQuery. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the onsubmit event isn't being handled, then your form isn't being submitted.

do you have one of the following in your form?

```
<input type='submit' ... />

<input type='image' ... />
```

The two elements above when clicked (or activated with space/enter) will submit the form. the onsubmit event handler you have should then catch it and the return false should stop the default action (changing page).

Also, your ajax.Request call doesn't actually seem to use any of the form information from the form itself. Ajax.Request needs to know what information to send.

**edit**
You were minssing a closing parentheses. use the following

```
<form name="requestReservationForm" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('admin/process/process_reservation_request.php', {onSuccess: function() {alert('Success');} , onFailure: function() {alert('Failure');}, method:'post', parameters:Form.serialize(this) }); return false;">
```

Comment: Yes I have the type="submit' in the form. (I added more html in the question). I see that I have not sent the form values. It seems I can use 'parameters:Form.serialize(this)'  The form still does not seem to submit at all however.